# Adding property to document $set not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

here is my code to add `token` and `reset_password_expires` property but it is not adding these properties

```
user.findByIdAndUpdate(result._id,
    {token: token, reset_password_expires: Date.now() + 86400000},
    { upsert: true, new: true },
    function(err,result){
       console.log(result);
   })
```

Comment: What is the result of simple find with these parameters?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the user schema?